# How to use autoresizingmask to stop components of UITableViewCell disappearing when editing? (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, autoresizingmask

I have a custom UITableViewCell which contains 3 UILabels. Two of these labels are aligned with the left hand side of the cell, the other one is aligned on the right hand side. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

The issue I'm having is when the UITableView is in editing mode. I have been trying to stop the labels on the right from disappearing off the side of the screen through the use of AutoResizingMasks but I'm not having any luck. Here is what happens:

[image]

The code I have been playing around with comes from my subclasses UITableViewCell. Here is my code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) 
    {
        // Setup the cells accessory
        self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        // Setup the cell background
        self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Plain_Cell.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

        // Setup the Main label (fruit names)
        mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
        mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

        // Setup the dates label
        datesLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        datesLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        datesLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:datesLabel];

        // Setup the milage label
        distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        distanceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        distanceLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        distanceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:distanceLabel];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    mainLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 39);
    datesLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 58, 184, 21);
    distanceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(205, 58, 85, 21);

    mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    datesLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    distanceLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
}
```

**NOTE:** Please scroll down for more code!

I haven't had much luck with it though. Please can someone help me out?

Comment: My guess is that the content view is moving and becoming flush with the right edge of the cell. Did you try leaving an 8px margin to the right of your right side labels?

Comment: also, i don't see where you set up your autoresizing masks?

Comment: Hi I have included code that sets the autoresizingmasks at the bottom of the code block.

Comment: the `autoresizingMask` is a policy--it should be set before you layout your subviews. i.e. put your labels where you want them for the current size, and set your autoresizing masks, then they will be repositioned automatically when your layer's bounds change

Comment: What i'm saying is, move the code you have out of `layoutSubviews` above into your `-init` routine. When your view resizes, your labels will be resized according to their autoresize masks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are aligning your text to the right, but not the label. Try this:

```
...
// Setup the mileage label
distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
distanceLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
distanceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
distanceLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
distanceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:distanceLabel];
```

This will lock the right margin where it is and allow the left margin to shrink when the view shrinks.